# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Component javax.faces.component.html.HtmlDataTable is no org.apache.myfaces.custom.datalist.HtmlDataList

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

In my JSF application I am using data table & data list from tomhawk`s implementation as well as  but sometimes I get following exception. This happens only when I am using Chrome browser only.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Component javax.faces.component.html.HtmlDataTable is no org.apache.myfaces.custom.datalist.HtmlDataList
    org.apache.myfaces.custom.datalist.HtmlDataListTag.setProperties(HtmlDataListTag.java:117)
    javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentTag.createComponent(UIComponentTag.java:209)
    javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.createChild(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:476)
    javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.findComponent(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:660)
    javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.doStartTag(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:1126)
    org.apache.jsp.HomeV_jsp._jspx_meth_t_005fdataList_005f0(HomeV_jsp.java:3903)
    org.apache.jsp.HomeV_jsp._jspx_meth_h_005fform_005f1(HomeV_jsp.java:3861)
    org.apache.jsp.HomeV_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005fview_005f0(HomeV_jsp.java:450)
    org.apache.jsp.HomeV_jsp._jspService(HomeV_jsp.java:155)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:408)
    com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.executePageToBuildView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:442)
    com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:115)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:106)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:251)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:144)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:245)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:696)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:667)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:67)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    com.advernture.discountbox.security.PageFilter.doFilter(PageFilter.java:43)
```

Does anyone has any clue about what might be happening here?
The code which causes this is as follows:

```
                                        <h:form id="browse_by_categry_frm">
                                        <div id="tagcloud">
                                            <t:dataList id="offer_cloud_table" value="#{CityCatagoryB.ctgryLstAsStr}" var="cat" binding="#{FindB.data}" layout="simple">
                                                <span style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px">
                                                    <h:commandLink value="#{cat}" action="#{FindB.doFind}" styleClass="subMenu"/>
                                                </span>                                                            
                                            </t:dataList>
                                        </div>
                                    </h:form>
```

Comment: what kind of object is FindB.data ?

Comment: It is of type javax.faces.component.UIData

Comment: isn't it supposed to be a HtmlDataList object , e.g private eHtmlDataList data; //with getter/setter ?

Answer (score 2):

The `binding="#{FindB.data}"` should refer to a property which is used by only **one** component. This exception indicates that the bean is session scoped and that you're sharing the same `binding="#{FindB.data}"` on a `<h:dataTable>` component somewhere else in the webapp. That it occurs in Chrome only is probably because it was the only browser where you have opened the other page with `<h:dataTable>` in the same session beforehand.

Make sure that you don't share the property behind `binding` among multiple components. Otherwise your bean has really to be in the request scope. Or, look for a way to get rid of `binding`, perhaps by making the `value` a `DataModel`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a binding problem. In your FindB bean you have

```
private HtmlDataTable data;
//getters/setters
```

But you should have:

```
private HtmlDataListdata;
//getters/setters
```

instead. Because t:dataList has to be bound to a reference of type org.apache.myfaces.custom.datalist.HtmlDataList.

Answer (score 0):

kindly when you are set your list as the following:

```
/**
 * Setter Related Report Link Roles.
 * 
 * @param relatedReportLinkRoles: Related Report Link Roles.
 */
public void setRelatedReportLinkRoles(List relatedReportLinkRoles) {
    this.relatedReportLinkRoles = relatedReportLinkRoles;
}
```

instead of that you must use the following:

```
/**
 * Setter Related Report Link Roles.
 * 
 * @param relatedReportLinkRoles: Related Report Link Roles.
 */
public void setRelatedReportLinkRoles(List relatedReportLinkRoles) {
    this.relatedReportLinkRoles = relatedReportLinkRoles;

    if(roleRelatedReportDataTable != null) {

        roleRelatedReportDataTable.setValue(relatedReportLinkRoles);
    }
}
```